# Heavy GC in Android while displaying animated .gif

Tags: android, animation, memory-management, garbage-collection, gif

In my Game i use Animated gif ( the standart movie decoder from android did not work for me), but this Code worked perfectly on all Android versions i testet so far:

here is the decoder:

```
import java.util.Vector;
import java.io.InputStream;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
public class GIFDecode {

    public static final int STATUS_OK = 0;
    public static final int STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR = 1;
    public static final int STATUS_OPEN_ERROR = 2;

    protected InputStream in;
    protected int status;

    protected int width; // full image width
    protected int height; // full image height
    protected boolean gctFlag; // global color table used
    protected int gctSize; // size of global color table
    protected int loopCount = 1; // iterations; 0 = repeat forever

    protected int[] gct; // global color table
    protected int[] lct; // local color table
    protected int[] act; // active color table

    protected int bgIndex; // background color index
    protected int bgColor; // background color
    protected int lastBgColor; // previous bg color
    protected int pixelAspect; // pixel aspect ratio

    protected boolean lctFlag; // local color table flag
    protected boolean interlace; // interlace flag
    protected int lctSize; // local color table size

    protected int ix, iy, iw, ih; // current image rectangle
    protected int lrx, lry, lrw, lrh;
    protected Bitmap image; // current frame
    protected Bitmap lastImage; // previous frame
    protected int frameindex=0;

    public int getFrameindex() {
            return frameindex;
    }

    public void recycle(){
            if(image != null){
                    image.recycle();
                    image = null;
            }
            if(lastImage != null){
                    lastImage.recycle();
                    lastImage = null;
            }

    }


    public void setFrameindex(int frameindex) {
            this.frameindex = frameindex;
            if(frameindex>frames.size()-1){
                    frameindex=0;  
            }
    }

    protected byte[] block = new byte[256]; // current data block
    protected int blockSize = 0; // block size

    // last graphic control extension info
    protected int dispose = 0;
    // 0=no action; 1=leave in place; 2=restore to bg; 3=restore to prev
    protected int lastDispose = 0;
    protected boolean transparency = false; // use transparent color
    protected int delay = 0; // delay in milliseconds
    protected int transIndex; // transparent color index

    protected static final int MaxStackSize = 4096;
    // max decoder pixel stack size

    // LZW decoder working arrays
    protected short[] prefix;
    protected byte[] suffix;
    protected byte[] pixelStack;
    protected byte[] pixels;

    protected Vector<GifFrame> frames; // frames read from current file
    protected int frameCount;

    static class GifFrame {
            public GifFrame(Bitmap im, int del) {
                    image = im;
                    delay = del;
            }

            public Bitmap image;
            public int delay;
    }

    /**
    * Gets display duration for specified frame.
    *
    * @param n
    *            int index of frame
    * @return delay in milliseconds
    */
    public int getDelay(int n) {
    delay = -1;
    if ((n >= 0) && (n < frameCount)) {
    delay = ((GifFrame) frames.elementAt(n)).delay;
    }
    return delay;
    }


    public int getFrameCount() {
            return frameCount;
    }

    public Bitmap getImage() {
            return getFrame(0);
    }
    public int getLoopCount() {
            return loopCount;
    }
    protected void setPixels() {
            int[] dest = new int[width * height];
            // fill in starting image contents based on last image's dispose code
            if (lastDispose > 0) {
                    if (lastDispose == 3) {
                            // use image before last
                            int n = frameCount - 2;
                            if (n > 0) {
                                    lastImage = getFrame(n - 1);
                            } else {
                                    lastImage = null;
                            }
                    }
                    if (lastImage != null) {
                            lastImage.getPixels(dest, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
                            // copy pixels 
                            if (lastDispose == 2) {
                                    // fill last image rect area with background color
                                    int c = 0;
                                    if (!transparency) {
                                            c = lastBgColor;
                                    }
                                    for (int i = 0; i < lrh; i++) {
                                            int n1 = (lry + i) * width + lrx;
                                            int n2 = n1 + lrw;
                                            for (int k = n1; k < n2; k++) {
                                                    dest[k] = c;
                                            }
                                    }
                            }
                    }
            }

            // copy each source line to the appropriate place in the destination
            int pass = 1;
            int inc = 8;
            int iline = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < ih; i++) {
                    int line = i;
                    if (interlace) {
                            if (iline >= ih) {
                                    pass++;
                                    switch (pass) {
                                            case 2:
                                                    iline = 4;
                                                    break;
                                            case 3:
                                                    iline = 2;
                                                    inc = 4;
                                                    break;
                                            case 4:
                                                    iline = 1;
                                                    inc = 2;
                                    }
                            }
                            line = iline;
                            iline += inc;
                    }
                    line += iy;
                    if (line < height) {
                            int k = line * width;
                            int dx = k + ix; // start of line in dest
                            int dlim = dx + iw; // end of dest line
                            if ((k + width) < dlim) {
                                    dlim = k + width; // past dest edge
                            }
                            int sx = i * iw; // start of line in source
                            while (dx < dlim) {
                                    // map color and insert in destination
                                    int index = ((int) pixels[sx++]) & 0xff;
                                    int c = act[index];
                                    if (c != 0) {
                                            dest[dx] = c;
                                    }
                                    dx++;
                            }
                    }
            }
            image = Bitmap.createBitmap(dest, width, height,Config.ARGB_8888);
    }

    public Bitmap getFrame(int n) {
            Bitmap im = null;
            if ((n >= 0) && (n < frameCount)) {
                    im = ((GifFrame) frames.elementAt(n)).image;
            }
            return im;
    }
    public Bitmap next(){
            frameindex++;
            if(frameindex>frames.size()-1){
                    frameindex=0;  
            }
    return  ((GifFrame) frames.elementAt(frameindex)).image;
    }
    public int read(InputStream is) {
            init();
            if (is != null) {
                    in = is;
                    readHeader();
                    if (!err()) {
                            readContents();
                            if (frameCount < 0) {
                                    status = STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR;
                            }
                    }
            } else {
                    status = STATUS_OPEN_ERROR;
            }
            try {
                    is.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return status;
    }
    protected void decodeImageData() {
            int NullCode = -1;
            int npix = iw * ih;
            int available, clear, code_mask, code_size, end_of_information, in_code, old_code, bits, code, count, i, datum, data_size, first, top, bi, pi;

            if ((pixels == null) || (pixels.length < npix)) {
                    pixels = new byte[npix]; // allocate new pixel array
            }
            if (prefix == null) {
                    prefix = new short[MaxStackSize];
            }
            if (suffix == null) {
                    suffix = new byte[MaxStackSize];
            }
            if (pixelStack == null) {
                    pixelStack = new byte[MaxStackSize + 1];
            }
            // Initialize GIF data stream decoder.
            data_size = read();
            clear = 1 << data_size;
            end_of_information = clear + 1;
            available = clear + 2;
            old_code = NullCode;
            code_size = data_size + 1;
            code_mask = (1 << code_size) - 1;
            for (code = 0; code < clear; code++) {
                    prefix[code] = 0;
                    suffix[code] = (byte) code;
            }

            // Decode GIF pixel stream.
            datum = bits = count = first = top = pi = bi = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < npix; ) {
                    if (top == 0) {
                            if (bits < code_size) {
                                    // Load bytes until there are enough bits for a code.
                                    if (count == 0) {
                                            // Read a new data block.
                                            count = readBlock();
                                            if (count <= 0) {
                                                    break;
                                            }
                                            bi = 0;
                                    }
                                    datum += (((int) block[bi]) & 0xff) << bits;
                                    bits += 8;
                                    bi++;
                                    count--;
                                    continue;
                            }
                            // Get the next code.
                            code = datum & code_mask;
                            datum >>= code_size;
                            bits -= code_size;

                            // Interpret the code
                            if ((code > available) || (code == end_of_information)) {
                                    break;
                            }
                            if (code == clear) {
                                    // Reset decoder.
                                    code_size = data_size + 1;
                                    code_mask = (1 << code_size) - 1;
                                    available = clear + 2;
                                    old_code = NullCode;
                                    continue;
                            }
                            if (old_code == NullCode) {
                                    pixelStack[top++] = suffix[code];
                                    old_code = code;
                                    first = code;
                                    continue;
                            }
                            in_code = code;
                            if (code == available) {
                                    pixelStack[top++] = (byte) first;
                                    code = old_code;
                            }
                            while (code > clear) {
                                    pixelStack[top++] = suffix[code];
                                    code = prefix[code];
                            }
                            first = ((int) suffix[code]) & 0xff;
                            // Add a new string to the string table,
                            if (available >= MaxStackSize) {
                                    break;
                            }
                            pixelStack[top++] = (byte) first;
                            prefix[available] = (short) old_code;
                            suffix[available] = (byte) first;
                            available++;
                            if (((available & code_mask) == 0)&& (available < MaxStackSize)) {
                                    code_size++;
                                    code_mask += available;
                            }
                            old_code = in_code;
                    }

                    // Pop a pixel off the pixel stack.
                    top--;
                    pixels[pi++] = pixelStack[top];
                    i++;
            }
            for (i = pi; i < npix; i++) {
                    pixels[i] = 0; // clear missing pixels
            }
    }

    protected boolean err() {
            return status != STATUS_OK;
    }

    protected void init() {
            status = STATUS_OK;
            frameCount = 0;
            frames = new Vector<GifFrame>();
            gct = null;
            lct = null;
    }
    protected int read() {
            int curByte = 0;
            try {
                    curByte = in.read();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    status = STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR;
            }
            return curByte;
    }
    protected int readBlock() {
            blockSize = read();
            int n = 0;
            if (blockSize > 0) {
                    try {
                            int count = 0;
                            while (n < blockSize) {
                                    count = in.read(block, n, blockSize - n);
                                    if (count == -1) {
                                            break;
                                    }
                                    n += count;
                            }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (n < blockSize) {
                            status = STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR;
                    }
            }
            return n;
    }
    protected int[] readColorTable(int ncolors) {
            int nbytes = 3 * ncolors;
            int[] tab = null;
            byte[] c = new byte[nbytes];
            int n = 0;
            try {
                    n = in.read(c);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (n < nbytes) {
                    status = STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR;
            } else {
                    tab = new int[256]; // max size to avoid bounds checks
                    int i = 0;
                    int j = 0;
                    while (i < ncolors) {
                            int r = ((int) c[j++]) & 0xff;
                            int g = ((int) c[j++]) & 0xff;
                            int b = ((int) c[j++]) & 0xff;
                            tab[i++] = 0xff000000 | (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
                    }
            }
            return tab;
    }

    protected void readContents() {
            // read GIF file content blocks
            boolean done = false;
            while (!(done || err())) {
                    int code = read();
                    switch (code) {        
                    case 0x2C: // image separator
                            readImage();
                            break;
                    case 0x21: // extension
                            code = read();
                            switch (code) {
                                    case 0xf9: // graphics control extension
                                            readGraphicControlExt();
                                            break;
                                    case 0xff: // application extension
                                            readBlock();
                                            String app = "";
                                            for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
                                                    app += (char) block[i];
                                            }
                                            if (app.equals("NETSCAPE2.0")) {
                                                    readNetscapeExt();
                                            } else {
                                                    skip(); // don't care
                                            }
                                            break;
                                    default: // uninteresting extension
                                            skip();
                            }
                            break;
                    case 0x3b: // terminator
                            done = true;
                            break;
                    case 0x00: // bad byte, but keep going and see what happens
                            break;
                    default:
                            status = STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR;
                    }
            }
    }

    protected void readGraphicControlExt() {
            read(); // block size
            int packed = read(); // packed fields
            dispose = (packed & 0x1c) >> 2; // disposal method
            if (dispose == 0) {
                    dispose = 1; // elect to keep old image if discretionary
            }
            transparency = (packed & 1) != 0;

            delay = readShort() * 10; // delay in milliseconds
            transIndex = read(); // transparent color index
            read(); // block terminator
    }

    protected void readHeader() {
            String id = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                    id += (char) read();
            }
            if (!id.startsWith("GIF")) {
                    status = STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR;
                    return;
            }
            readLSD();
            if (gctFlag && !err()) {
                    gct = readColorTable(gctSize);
                    bgColor = gct[bgIndex];
            }
    }

    protected void readImage() {
            ix = readShort(); // (sub)image position & size
            iy = readShort();
            iw = readShort();
            ih = readShort();
            int packed = read();
            lctFlag = (packed & 0x80) != 0; // 1 - local color table flag
            interlace = (packed & 0x40) != 0; // 2 - interlace flag
            // 3 - sort flag
            // 4-5 - reserved
            lctSize = 2 << (packed & 7); // 6-8 - local color table size   
            if (lctFlag) {
                    lct = readColorTable(lctSize); // read table
                    act = lct; // make local table active
            } else {
                    act = gct; // make global table active
                    if (bgIndex == transIndex) {
                            bgColor = 0;
                    }
            }
            int save = 0;
            if (transparency) {
                    save = act[transIndex];
                    act[transIndex] = 0; // set transparent color if specified
            }
            if (act == null) {
                    status = STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR; // no color table defined
            }
            if (err()) {
                    return;
            }
            decodeImageData(); // decode pixel data
            skip();
            if (err()) {
                    return;
            }
            frameCount++;
            // create new image to receive frame data
            image = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,Config.ARGB_8888 );// Config.RGB_565);
            //createImage(width, height);  
            setPixels(); // transfer pixel data to image   
            frames.addElement(new GifFrame(image, delay)); // add image to frame
            // list
            if (transparency) {
                    act[transIndex] = save;
            }
            resetFrame();
    }

    protected void readLSD() {
            // logical screen size
            width = readShort();
            height = readShort();  
            // packed fields
            int packed = read();
            gctFlag = (packed & 0x80) != 0; // 1 : global color table flag
            // 2-4 : color resolution
            // 5 : gct sort flag
            gctSize = 2 << (packed & 7); // 6-8 : gct size 
            bgIndex = read(); // background color index
            pixelAspect = read(); // pixel aspect ratio
    }

    protected void readNetscapeExt() {
            do {
                    readBlock();
                    if (block[0] == 1) {
                            // loop count sub-block
                            int b1 = ((int) block[1]) & 0xff;
                            int b2 = ((int) block[2]) & 0xff;
                            loopCount = (b2 << 8) | b1;
                    }
            } while ((blockSize > 0) && !err());
    }

    protected int readShort() {
            // read 16-bit value, LSB first
            return read() | (read() << 8);
    }

    protected void resetFrame() {
            lastDispose = dispose;
            lrx = ix;
            lry = iy;
            lrw = iw;
            lrh = ih;
            lastImage = image;
            lastBgColor = bgColor;
            dispose = 0;
            transparency = false;
            delay = 0;
            lct = null;
    }

    /**
    * Skips variable length blocks up to and including next zero length block.
    */
    protected void skip() {
            do {
                    readBlock();
            } while ((blockSize > 0) && !err());
    }
```

}

and here is how i use it:

```
 decode = new GIFDecode();

 decode.read(getAssets().open(path));


            while (true) {
                            framepos = decode.getFrameindex();
                            delay = decode.getDelay(framepos);
                            try {
                                    Thread.sleep(delay);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        bitmap = decode.next();
                            bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, bitmap.getWidth()*scale,bitmap.getHeight()*scale, false);
            }
    }
```

my only problem is the heavy garbage collection it slows my game down from 30 fps to almost 17-18 fps 
can anyone tell me please how i can avoid those collections ?
(they occure only while using this gif decoder)

gc is as follows:

```
...
03-27 16:29:34.904: D/dalvikvm(1792): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1084K, 10% free 21750K/24007K, paused 7ms, total 7ms
03-27 16:29:35.172: D/dalvikvm(1792): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1228K, 10% free 21751K/24007K, paused 9ms, total 17ms
03-27 16:29:35.493: D/dalvikvm(1792): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1226K, 10% free 21750K/24007K, paused 21ms, total 40ms
03-27 16:29:35.791: D/dalvikvm(1792): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1222K, 10% free 21752K/24007K, paused 7ms, total 15ms
03-27 16:29:36.062: D/dalvikvm(1792): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1339K, 10% free 21751K/24007K, paused 7ms, total 7ms
03-27 16:29:36.402: D/dalvikvm(1792): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1339K, 10% free 21751K/24007K, paused 19ms, total 26ms
03-27 16:29:36.701: D/dalvikvm(1792): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1348K, 10% free 21751K/24007K, paused 7ms, total 16ms
03-27 16:29:37.014: D/dalvikvm(1792): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1215K, 10% free 21752K/24007K, paused 0ms, total 0ms
03-27 16:29:37.301: D/dalvikvm(1792): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1221K, 10% free 21751K/24007K, paused 9ms, total 9ms
03-27 16:29:37.582: D/dalvikvm(1792): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1289K, 10% free 21750K/24007K, paused 18ms, total 24ms
03-27 16:29:37.863: D/dalvikvm(1792): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1168K, 10% free 21752K/24007K, paused 7ms, total 7ms
03-27 16:29:38.164: D/dalvikvm(1792): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 964K, 10% free 21750K/24007K, paused 0ms, total 0ms
03-27 16:29:38.503: D/dalvikvm(1792): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1354K, 10% free 21751K/24007K, paused 25ms, total 25ms
03-27 16:29:38.851: D/dalvikvm(1792): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1342K, 10% free 21752K/24007K, paused 30ms, total 49ms
03-27 16:29:39.151: D/dalvikvm(1792): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1228K, 10% free 21752K/24007K, paused 10ms, total 26ms
03-27 16:29:39.483: D/dalvikvm(1792): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 967K, 10% free 21750K/24007K, paused 20ms, total 40ms
03-27 16:29:39.781: D/dalvikvm(1792): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 965K, 10% free 21750K/24007K, paused 23ms, total 24ms
03-27 16:29:40.102: D/dalvikvm(1792): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1350K, 10% free 21752K/24007K, paused 23ms, total 23ms
03-27 16:29:40.411: D/dalvikvm(1792): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1352K, 10% free 21752K/24007K, paused 8ms, total 17ms
...
```

How can i reuse the allocated Memory instead of throwing it away everytime?

Comment: Post your code here, rather than linking to pastebin! Also, its nearly impossible to say what causing the Garbage Collector to start. It runs "automatically" when there is need to free some of the allocated memory. You can't controll it's behaviour.

Comment: sorry, first time i ask a question on stackoverflow i changed it :o

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem is that this line:

```
bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, bitmap.getWidth()*scale,bitmap.getHeight()*scale, false);
```

causes an allocation, which (I presume) quickly becomes garbage. Perhaps you'd do better to create these objects as a single pass over the image data before starting to animate. Then, just use those Bitmap objects by reference instead of recreating a new one each frame.

Comment: my gif file is about 12 kb big and has 107 images. I tried to create an array and cache every image, the problem is then an out of memory error. The Array consumes more than 11 mb ram

Comment: i changed my game, so that it is caching .gif only when there is enough heap with: ((Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()/1024)/1000). It returns the heap size in MB. If Anyone has a better idea please tell... FPS this way goes up to 30 /30 with caching :) thanks